# Euler Project 4: Finding the largest palindrome product

Tags: arrays, c, palindrome

So, I've wrote several function prototypes for finding the largest palindrome products. The idea is that put the original number into an array in reverse order then convert the array into a number as reverse number. Then compare the reverse number with original number to see if these two numbers are equal or not. However, I am stuck at implementing these functions prototypes in main method. If yes, then it is a palindrome product/ Any suggestions? Please, have mercy I am new to C

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    // Taking a number and reverse it. Put it in reverse order into an array. Then, convert all elements in the array into an array again
    //Ex: Original number = 6542
    //Input: "6542" -> arr[4] = {2,4,5,6} -> Output: "2456"
    //Original Number = 6542; Reverse Number = 2456
    //Original Number != Reverse Number -> The number is not palindrome. Palindrome Number Example: 456654, 1, 2332.
    
    
    int convert_reverse_num (int original_num, int digits_count){
        int arr_size = digits_count;
        int x = original_num;
        int final_reverse_num = 0;
        
        int *arr;
        arr = (int*)malloc (arr_size * sizeof(int));
    
        //convert the number into arr array by placing the first index with the last trailing digit on the right
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
            arr[i] = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        
    
        
        //Adding all values in the array into a number
        //starting from the first index of the array which has the value of the last digit of the number
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
            final_reverse_num *=  10;
            final_reverse_num += arr[i];
        }
        free(arr);
        return final_reverse_num;
    }
    
    
    
    //Check the number is palindrome or not by comparing the original num and reverse num
    
bool is_palindrome(int original_num, int reverse_num){
        int x = original_num;
        int y = reverse_num;
    
        if(x == y)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    
    }
    
    
    
    //Count number of digits in a number in order to declare the buffer size
    
int count_digit_num(int product_digits){
        int y = product_digits;
        
        int digits_count = 0;
        while(y!=0){
            y /= 10;
            ++digits_count;
        }return digits_count;
    }
    
    
    
    
    //Find all possible products from two ndigits(2 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits) number
    // Examples: 1 digits: 1*2.  2 digits: 12*13. 3 digits: 100 * 999
    
int find_largest_palindrome(int ndigits){
        
        int min = 1;
        int max;
        int smallest_num;
        int largest_num = 0;
        int product = 0;
    
        //Finding the minima. 1 digit = 1; 2 digits = 10; 3 digits = 100
        smallest_num = min * pow(10, ndigits-1);
        
    
        //Finding the maxima. 1 digits = 9; 2 digits = 99; 3 digits = 999
        for (int i = 0; i < ndigits; i++){
            max  =  9 * pow(10, i);
            largest_num += max;
        }
        
    
        //All possible products from minima and maxima
        for (int x = largest_num; x >= smallest_num; x--){
            for (int y = largest_num; y >= smallest_num; y--){
                product = x * y;
                
            }
        
        }
        return product;
    }
    
    int main(){
    
    return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: My solution to this problem converted the product to a string and tested if it is a palindrome. It was one function (`main`). No `malloc`, no `pow` just 3 nested loops.

Comment: You have all these useful functions lying around, but you never get around to calling them: Your `main` just returns 0, but it should probably call `find_largest_palindrome` and print its result. In `find_largest_palindrome`, you dutifully calucalte each `product`, but you never check whether it `is_palindrome(product)` or whether it is the biggest one you found yet.

Comment: Did you get a result? Did you enter it? On Project Euler you should finish the problems unaided, or it would be considered cheating.

Comment: Rather than calculate all possible products and check for palindromes, start at the largest palindrome '999999' and try to factor it into two 3-digit numbers.  Calculating the next lower palindrome is simple but not obvious.

Comment: I know what the answer is since I already wrote a code that super simple all in main. But I want to try dynamic memory allocation in C. Because I want to understand the concept which is why this long version. I tried to printf and call `find_largest_palindrome` in the main method but it only printed out `100`. However, I tested `find_largest_palindrome` function before with printf statements underneath `product = x * y`. So, the problem must be `return` statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not really a good test case for dynamic memory allocation. You count the digits, then allocate memory accordingly, reverse the number and then free the array again. That's a lot of overhead. The largest int is about 2 billion, so just create an local array on the stack: `int arr[10];` plus a size counter. You don't even need an array if you merge the two `for` loops.

Comment: When you call the function from `main`, it just prints 100, which isn't a palindrome. So obviously some of your functions don't work. Will `is_palindrome(12321)` return true? Will `is_palindrome(123)` return false?

Comment: Yes, I tested every single function with unit tests and all the tests pass with the exception of `find_largest_palindrome`. So, I went ahead and use printf to test `find_largest_palindrome`. The printf statement inside the nested for loop is underneath `product = x * y`. And the output on the console displayed all possible values from 2 digits number. Hence, why I was confused about in the main method printf statement did not print out all possible values as in the printf in `find_largest_palindrome`